# Disable Household Creating on Adding Contact (Nonprofit)

Tags: npsp, nonprofit-starter-pack

i have a problem with disabling automatic account creating (household record type). There are no triggers for it or anything else. I found some options to disable it, but it was depricated and it doesnt work.

I am using Nonprofit success pack ver. 3.133

I found on internet, there should be some Household settings but i cant find it.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

Only thing i found is that contacts without relationship to account will be moved to account "Individiual"

Comment: Why do you want to disable this function? It's a core part of the NPSP Household Model, and remember that Contacts without Accounts are private and not visible to other users.

Comment: I know it is, but it making a lot of duplicities while creating contacts, accounts linked to some contacts etc. So the question is sill there, how to disable it :)

Comment: The best resource for the Nonprofit Success Pack is the [Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com), which is run by Salesforce.org.  It's a large community of NPSP users, consultants, and the Salesforce.org developers and support staff.